# No visible @interface for 'XYZPerson' declares selector 'initWithfirst:middlename:lastname'

Tags: objective-c

This is my first objective code. I tried and searched to my best abilities but I did not get a solution to my problem. This is my code;

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZPerson:NSObject

@property NSString *firstname;
@property NSString *lastname;
@property NSString *middlename;

-(void)saysomething;
-(instancetype) initWithfirst:(NSString *) firstname
                   middlename:(NSString *) middlename
                     lastname:(NSString *) lastname;

+(void) greeting;
@end
```

---

```
#import "Myproj.h"
@implementation XYZPerson

-(instancetype) initWithfirst:(NSString *) firstname
                   middlename:(NSString *) middlename
                     lastname:(NSString *) lastname
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
        _firstname=firstname;
        _middlename=middlename;
        _lastname=lastname;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) saysomething
{
    NSLog(@"Hi there %@ %@ %@",_firstname,_middlename,self.lastname);
    [XYZPerson greeting];
}

+(void) greeting
{
    NSLog(@"Have a great evening \n");
}
@end
```

---

When I try to create an object and initialize the properties its giving me an error

> No visible @interface for 'XYZPerson' declares selector 'initWithfirst:middlename:lastname'

What I don't understand is it keeps prompting me another init method that I used previously ([as seen in the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zj50.png))

I am unable to figure out the mistake, can somebody please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: just clean and run once the project product->clean

Comment: Also, just trying to build the project would probably solved the problem.